# Eclipse RCP get part instance

Tags: java, eclipse, reference, rcp

I am trying to get reference to part which is connected to Java class. I can use

```
`@PostConstruct
public void createComposite(Composite parent) {

}`
```

and then "parent" variable is what I need. But I want to have another method. I am trying to add static variable to save it like that:

```
public class BibliotekaZmianyPart {
private static Label label;
private static Button button;
private static Composite part;

@PostConstruct
public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
    part = parent;
}

public static void editBook() {
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    part.setLayout(layout);
    label = new Label(part, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("A label");
    button = new Button(part, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Press Me");
}}
```

and then "part" should be variable which I need - but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a static method like that referencing instance variables.

If you want to reference an **existing** part from another part you use the `EPartService` to find the part:

```
@Inject
EPartService partService;


MPart mpart = partService.findPart("part id");

BibliotekaZmianyPart part = (BibliotekaZmianyPart)mpart.getObject();

part.editBook();   // Using non-static 'editBook'
```

If the part is not already open you use the part service `showPart` method:

```
MPart mpart = partService.showPart("part id", PartState.ACTIVATE);

BibliotekaZmianyPart part = (BibliotekaZmianyPart)mpart.getObject();

part.editBook();
```

So your class would be:

```
public class BibliotekaZmianyPart {
private Label label;
private Button button;
private Composite part;

@PostConstruct
public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
    part = parent;
}

public void editBook() {
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    part.setLayout(layout);
    label = new Label(part, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("A label");
    button = new Button(part, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Press Me");

    // You probably need to call layout on the part
    part.layout();
}}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I need "Composite" variable to create label in my editBook() method. How can I get reference to "Composite parent" but in another method.

Comment: You still save the Composite in the constructor like you were doing and use a non-static `editBook` method (and don't use `static` for variables either). This code assumes that the part has already been created when you want to call `editBook`.

Comment: Now I'm useing your code when I call (now non-static) editBook() method but still it doesn't create new label. But when I copy code which create label to "createComposite" method then label is created but immediately after app start. I think that problem is with "part = parent" line.

Comment: Did you include the part.layout() call? Since you are adding to the Composite after it has been displayed it needs to be told to update

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thanks You very, very, very much.